# How to define a cell value as a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using a fixed file name in my code however I'd like to replace this fixed name with the value of a particular cell

I've looked extensively across threads to no luck - I'm quite new to coding so I've found similar issues but nothing I'm able to apply to my coding or adapt for exactly my needs

I've tried using

```
Set wbBook2 = Workbooks(wsSheet1_1.Range("O35").Value)
```

and a few other similar steps but to no avail

```
Dim wbBook1 As Workbook
Dim wsSheet1_1 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet1_2 As Worksheet

Dim wbBook2 As Workbook
Dim wsSheet2_1 As Worksheet

Set wbBook1 = Workbooks("Main File.xlsm")
Set wsSheet1_1 = wbBook1.Worksheets("Example1")
Set wsSheet1_2 = wbBook1.Worksheets("Example2")

Set wbBook2 = Workbooks("Look Up File.xlsm")
Set wsSheet2_1 = wbBook2.Worksheets("Example3")
```

The above allows me to use 'wbBook2.Activate' to switch to the workbook where the data is located & take the necessary actions however I'd like to be able to change from using "Look Up File.xlsm" to cell O35 on wsSheet1_1.

Currently I'm just ensuring my look-up file has the same name as is noted in the code but this would obviously lead to failure if this is accidentally re-named or a user titled this LookUp File (omitting the space) for example.

Note that 'wbBook2' will already be open when this code is used & the file name can change. The user separately defines the full file path & name (including .xlsm) which is then opened in a separate macro that needs to remain separate

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to loop through Workbooks and look for a match

```
Private Function set_wb(ByVal toName As String) As Workbook

    ' Function set_wb(<String>), returns Workbook Object on match.
    ' - if no match found, return Nothing
    ' - invokation example: Set wb1 = set_wb("Book1")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    For each wb in Application.Workbooks
       If wb.Name = toName Then
           Set set_wb = wb ' wb found
           Exit Function
       End If
    Next wb

    Set set_wb = Nothing ' wb not found
End Function
```

And would be invoked in your case the following way:

```
Set wbBook2 = set_wb(wsSheet1_1.Range("O35"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly! Unfortunately Private Functions are totally alien to me & I'm not too sure how to implement the above. I've tried simply removing my 'Set wbBook2' line & adding your above solution however this gives a Compile Error. In addition, I assume the invocation line would take the place of the first 'Set' only and this would be the only change? Or am I entirely off-track? Thanks

Comment: *[1/2]* You can ignore `Private` that is just scope declaration and completely irrelevant to your solution. Functions work similarly as procedures (`Sub`) only difference being, they return a value - in our case either a `Workbook` object or `Nothing`. Copy paste entire function in to the same module (presumably Sheet code) as the rest of your code

Comment: *[2/2]* Make sure you have your `wbBook1` and `wsSheet1` correctly declared and initalized (like in your example code). Once you do, you create a variable eg. `wbBook2` and use the function which will return the object according to the name from `Range("O35")` - in other words, the last line of my answer. Now the `Workbook` *(if it exists)* will be stored inside `wbBook2` variable